# aspx javascript enabling button and checkbox on scroll down

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is the html i'm using.  I'm trying to figure out why my button and checkbox never get set to enabled.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<script src="js/mootools-core-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function checkScrollHeight() {
        var textElement = document.getElementsByName("tosgareementdiv")[0].addEventListener("scroll", checkScrollHeight, false);
        if ((textElement.scrollTop + textElement.offsetHeight) >= textElement.scrollHeight) {
            document.getElementsByName("AcceptTOSButton")[0].disabled = false;
        }

    });
</script>
<div class="tosgareementdiv">
    <p>hi my stuff</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<asp:CheckBox ID="AcceptTOSCheckBox" Text="I Agree." runat="server" Enabled="false" />
    <asp:Button ID="AcceptTOSButton" Text="I Agree" runat="server" OnClick="AcceptTOSButton_Click"
        Enabled="false" />
</div>
</form>
```

I was following the example here but i'm not able to figure out how to get it to fire..

I know there is no code for the checkbox but why wont the button enable?

Comment: `checkScrollHeight` is never bound to any events or called. what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


$(function(){
            function checkScrollHeight() {

                if ((textElement.scrollTop + textElement.offsetHeight) >= textElement.scrollHeight) {
                    document.getElementById("AcceptTOSButton").disabled = false;
                }else{
                     document.getElementById("AcceptTOSButton").disabled = true;
               }

            };
           var textElement = document.getElementsByClassName("tosgareementdiv")[0];
          textElement.addEventListener("scroll", checkScrollHeight, false);
});
```

Comment: Sushil - not still doesnt fire, does it had to do with it being an asp button?

Comment: @Mike I made required changes try now

Comment: Thanks again but it's still not firing